# Javascript injection into webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I know it exists a lot of questions about that but i don't understand why my following code does not work anymore

Here is my code :

```
private void init() {
    webview.setWebViewClient(new FormWebViewClient());
    webview.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(data, "BASE64"));
}

private class FormWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            LOGD(TAG, "Url : " + url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:" +"document.getElementsByClassName('my_class_name')[0].value = '" + myValue + "';" +
    }
}
```

My original webview is overrided and it displays only `myValue` in the page instead of plenty of informations.

If anybody knows why i have this behavior ...

Thx

---

EDIT :

and the part of html

```
<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="19" autocomplete="off" name="CARD_NUMBER" id="CARD_NUMBER" class="my_class_name" value="">
```

Comment: May be this doesn't answer your question but i think you are creating a kind of loop since you call loadUrl inside of `onPageFinished` and `loadUrl`

Comment: Above comment sounds legit. can you post your html file so that we could test it at our end?

Comment: In fact, it is a payment webview from Atos so i'm not sure i'm allowed to post html

Comment: I've added html part

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I've found the answer :

I have to add `void(0);` at the end of JavaScript instruction like this :

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:" +"document.getElementsByClassName('my_class_name')[0].value = '" + myValue + "';void(0);")
```

Comment: This was beyond helpful! Thank you so much. How did you figure out that you need void(0); at the end of it?

Comment: This was of huge help. I also got the same problem. With Browser update, my code stopped working. This resolved it!